# What is the accepted convention for transcribing audio speech dysfluencies and repeated utterances?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, speech

If this question belongs in another topic, refer me to the correct site.
I came across some transcripts in which the text says

```
ah
```

When the audio actually says

```
uh.
```

Another example is when the person says, 'no' multiple times. Instead of writing it several times, it is written as

```
no, no, no no, etc.
```

Wgat's the reason behind these? Is there a type of grammar audio-to-text transcribers use?

Comment: I've seen BrE transcription of "uh"/"um" utterances as "em" or "erm", which I feel is just wrong because it is translating the NAmer flavor right out of the dialogue.

Comment: There is no such convention.

You either transcribe exactly what was uttered or you try your best to "clean it up", in either case to the best of your ability.